# ASP.Net MVC 5 Html.BeginForm onsubmit and model with required attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have required attribute on my model properties but I added a "spinner" to show processing request in form onsubmit. Now, even though that it didn't submit the form, it shows the "spinner" i created, and stuck on the overlay but the textbox with required attribute is in focus.

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "UserAccount", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit="spinner()"}))
{
//Html.TextBoxes for model properties with required
}
<div id="spinner" hidden="">
    <div>
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-pulse" style="color: white; font-    size: 50px;"></i>
        <label style="color: white; font-size: 50px;">Processing</label>
    </div>
</div>




<script>
function spinner() {
    $("#spinner").show();
}
</script>
```

Is their a way to check first if the "required" attribute is satisfied before accessing the onsubmit function?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ***submitHandler*** function to ***validator***. [Here](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/Views/Account/Login.cshtml#L60) is the complete code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {

      $("form").data("validator").settings.submitHandler = function (form) {
         $("#submit-button").html("<i class=\"fa fa-spinner fa-pulse\"></i> Signing In...")
            .prop('disabled', true);
         form.submit();
      };
   });
</script>
```

Comment: it says that .data is undefined

Comment: It seems that you have more than one form tags in a page. If so, you'll need to target it by id - For example, `using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "UserAccount", FormMethod.Post, new { id="form1"}))`, and `$("#form1").data("validator")`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need client side validation before form has been submitted you have added required attribute on properties that is fine now make a client side validation work you need to add some js which is handle all validations client side

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

Below is list of js you need

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

You need `jquery.validate.unobstrusive.js` to make client validation work

Second you need to change in web config as well

```
 <appSettings>  
        ...
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 

        ...
 </appSettings>
```

Fore more infomration find [what is unobtrusive-validation](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-unobtrusive-validation/) on this blog.

Using this your form is not submitted before all fields are validated properly like `Required`,`Range` etc which you have mentioned on properties

After adding this bunch of code you can validate form in on button click as well as below

```
$("#btn1").click(function (e) {

   e.preventDefault();

   // now trigger the form validation, result is 1 or 0
   var result = $('form').valid();  
   if(!result)
   {
     // Do some stuff if form is not valid
   }
});
```