# Jquery validations are not working in my mvc4 project

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, fullcalendar

I m trying to put jquery validations in my dropdown list in full calendar add event , but i don't know why any of the solution is not working .. can anyone help?

HTML code:

```html
<div id="add_task_dialog_box" class="hide">
<form id="form_data" method="post" class="form-horizontal" style="display: none;">
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <div class="row class1 " style="padding: 10px;">
        <span><span class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <label for="dd1" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 13px; font-type: Arial; font-family: Arial Unicode MS">
                Project Name</label></span> <span class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Task_runsModel.Project_Id, db.getProjects(a), "---Select---", new { style = "width:200px;", id = "myproject", name = "Project", @class = "required" })</span>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Task_runsModel.Project_Id)
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="row class1 " style="padding: 10px;">
        <span><span class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <label style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 13px; font-type: Arial; font-family: Arial Unicode MS">
                Select Task</label></span> <span class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Task_runsModel.Task_Id, db.getTasks(a, c), "--Select--", new { style = "width:200px;", id = "mytask", name = "Task", @class = "required" })</span>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Task_runsModel.Task_Id)
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="row class1" style="padding: 10px;">
        <span><span class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <label style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 13px; font-type: Arial; font-family: Arial Unicode MS">
                Task status
            </label>
        </span><span class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 ">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Task_runsModel.status, db.getStatus(), "---Select---", new { style = "width:200px", id = "taskstatus", name = "Status", @class = "required" })
        </span>
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Task_runsModel.status)
        </span>
    </div>


    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
        <div id="chatarea" class="dropdown-toggle" style="float: left; padding-left: 20px;
            overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: auto;">
        </div>
        <b style="float: right; padding-right: 20px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"
            id="DisplayComment"></b>
    </div>
    @* <div id="commentdiv" class="dropdown-toggle" style=" padding-left: 20px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: auto;width:100%">

                <ul id="current_comments" type="none" style="font-weight:bold;">
                </ul> 
    </div>*@

     <div id="textareadiv" style="padding-top:3px;">
        <span class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-9 col-xs-12" style="padding-left: 12px; width: inherit;">@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Task_runsModel.comment1, new { id = "comment", ariahidden = "true", placeholder = "Write comment", @class = "form-control wp-editor-area", cols = "65", rows = "3", style = " width: calc(100%);" }) </span>

    </div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

jquery:

```
 jQuery(function ($) {


  //  $('#form_data').validate();

    $("#form_data").validate({    
    messages: {  
        Project_Id: {  
            required: "Eh ? empty username ?",  
            minLength: "At least 4 characters are necessary"  
        },  
        Task_Id: {  
            required: "password missing"  
        },  
        status: {  
            required: "please provide us your email, we promise we wont spam !",  
            email: "email id is not in correct format, eg: mail@yassershaikh.com"  
        }  
    }  
});
```

Comment: if you used data annotations on your c# model and jquery validate none obtrusive, you shouldn't need to hook up the validation manually like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorate your model with Validation Attributes as below you don't need to write it in jquery below is a simple model class with decorated attribute this is called Data annotation for Model Validation

```
public class UserModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Name")]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Email Address")]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$", 
    ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Correct Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; } 

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Mobile No")]
    [Display(Name = "Mobile")]
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "The Mobile must contains 10 characters", MinimumLength = 10)] 
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
}
```

To make a MVC validation works please find [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43094223/2534646) or [THIS](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-unobtrusive-validation/) blog to set up MVC validation for your MVC project.

**Below are some basic Data annotations you can use**

**DisplayName**

specify the display name for a property.

**DisplayFormat**

specify the display format for a property like different format for Date proerty.

**Required**

Specify a property as required.

**ReqularExpression**

validate the value of a property by specified regular expression pattern.

**Range**

validate the value of a property with in a specified range of values.

**StringLength**

specify min and max length for a string property.

**MaxLength**

specify max length for a string property.

Comment: Yes it's working with jquery but you don't have to write custom code as you have wrote you just need to decorate your model rest of the things has been handled by MVC and jquery internally. If yon wants to know more about this please go through [this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/data-annotations-and-validation-in-mvc/)

Comment: I have done the same but as per my knowledge , jquery doesn't know anything about the validations we had done in the model, for this purpose jquery use jquery.validate () mrthod but don't know why it is not working

Comment: use `$("#form_data").valid()` and make sure you have added `<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>` and `<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>` this js in your page or master page layout

Comment: @aayushi you are on wrong track you need to read more about Data Annotation in MVC it' works behind the scene for let jquery know about our model validation MVC internally uses `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`

Comment: yes , i have used both and $("#form_data").valid() and now it works....

Comment: That's great :)